# Questions about Kohana's Auth module

Tags: kohana

I've been looking at the Kohana docs , for a project I'm planning to make that needs an user-system. I noticed the Auth module but when I tried to figure how to use it the docs were little to no help , so I searched the internet - but everything I found was either outdated or didn't answer my questions, so I was hoping you could direct me to a good tutorial on how to use the Auth module.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What Kohana version are you using?

Comment: The Kohana documentation can be a little rough at times, but I don't recall it lacking any important information regarding the Auth module. Can you be more specific about what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Have you read this http://docs.kohanaphp.com/addons/auth ?

First you need to create tables with the structure described in the document, then all you do is pass Input class variables inside of your Controller to the methods described in the document.

If this is to general description then go ahead and ask more detailed questions and I'd be happy to assist you.